# Ajuste da tela em css [fechado]

Tags: html, css

Ola

Eu tou com um problema ao ajustar as minhas divs

Eu na div da esquerda tenho com que a altura seja a 100% do conteúdo e eu queria que a div do meio e a div da direita fosse do mesmo tamanho que a div da esquerda mas que não queria fazer com px, ha alguma forma de ajustar as outras duas div ao mesmo tamanho que a div da direita?

Eu utilizo os vh para a altura das outras duas divs mas queria mudar isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.esquerda {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(/imagens/blackfundo2.jpg);
    padding: 35px 45px 35px 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%; 
}

.meio { 
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #3E3E3E;
    padding: 0;
}

.direita {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('imagens/blackfundo2.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3 esquerda">

    <h1 class="titulo1">Violência</h1>
    <h1 class="titulo12">doméstica</h1>
    <h1 class="titulo123">em portugal</h1>

<div class="Texto"> 
<h3> exemplo de texto </h3>
<h5 class="rage" >Todos os casos de violencia doméstica registados até á data currente em portugal no ano de 2019</h5>
</div>

<br>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="filtroselects">
  <img src="/imagens/iconfiltro.png" height="40px" width="40px"> Filtros
</button>

<div id="escolha">
<form id="selectsfiltro">
    <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <h6>Sexo:</h6>
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Localidade:</h6>
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>

    <div class="botesdefiltrar">
        <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
        <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
  </div>   
  </div>

  <br>

  <h5 id="denuncia">Caso saiba de algum caso de violencia doméstica
  <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader" class="denunciastyle" target="_blank">denuncie aqui</a>
  </h5> 

</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-6 meio">
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 direita">
<div>
```

**Obrigado a quem me tentou ajudar mas já consegui resolver, basicamente como estou a usar o boostrap automaticamente se tirar a altura ele ira se tentar adaptar a maior div que tenho logo as outras duas div vao ter o mesmo tamanho que a primeira div**

Comment: Porque usas "height: 100vh;" em vez de "height: 100%;"?

Comment: @Pbras pois se usar 100% de altura no mapa, o mapa vai desaparecer porque 100% de altura equivale ao conteúdo e o mapa não e propriamente um conteúdo extenso como o da div da esquerda.

Comment: Mas o mapa é um iframe certo? Podes meter o tamanho de iframe com 100% de altura para ficar do mesmo tamanho.

Comment: sim o mapa esta a 100% de altura da div por exemplo se a div tiver 100px de altura, o mapa vai ter 100px de altura mas se a div tiver 100% de altura e o mapa tambem nao vai ter tamanho nenhum pois cada um vai depender do outro e vai desaparecer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vc está usando Bootstrap. E aparentemente não está usando o Grid da maneira correta, pois vc não colocou as `COl-` dentro de um *container* com a classe `ROW`. a `ROW` tem `display:flex` e faz por padrão que todas as `COL-` tenham a mesma altura.

Então primeiro vc deve tirar esse `100VH` que vc colocou, e depois coloca todo o conteúdo dentro da `div` com classe `ROW`. Seu código tb tinha várias `divs` que vc abriu, mas não fechou, então eu corrigi isso...

Execute em tela cheia para ver melhor o resultado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <style>
  .esquerda {
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/101);
   padding: 35px 45px 35px 45px;
   text-align: center;
   background-size: 100%;
  }

  .meio {
   /* height: 100vh; */
   background-color: #3E3E3E;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .direita {
   /* height: 100vh; */
   background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
   background-size: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3 esquerda">

    <h1 class="titulo1">Violência</h1>
    <h1 class="titulo12">doméstica</h1>
    <h1 class="titulo123">em portugal</h1>

    <div class="Texto">
     <h3> exemplo de texto </h3>
     <h5 class="rage">Todos os casos de violencia doméstica registados até á data currente em portugal no
      ano de
      2019</h5>
    </div>

    <br>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id="filtroselects">
     <img src="/imagens/iconfiltro.png" height="40px" width="40px"> Filtros
    </button>

    <div id="escolha">
     <form id="selectsfiltro">
      <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
      <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
       <option></option>
       <option value="1">0-17</option>
       <option value="2">18-25</option>
       <option value="3">26-35</option>
       <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
      </select>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Sexo:</h6>
      <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
       <option></option>
       <option value="5">Masc</option>
       <option value="6">Fem</option>
      </select>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
      <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
       <option></option>
       <option value="7">Sim</option>
       <option value="8">Não</option>
      </select>


      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Localidade:</h6>
      <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
       <option></option>
       <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
       <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
       <option value="11">Bragança</option>
       <option value="12">Braga</option>
       <option value="13">Porto</option>
       <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
       <option value="15">Viseu</option>
       <option value="16">Guarda</option>
       <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
       <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
       <option value="19">Leiria</option>
       <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
       <option value="21">Santarém</option>
       <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
       <option value="23">Évora</option>
       <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
       <option value="25">Beja</option>
       <option value="26">Faro</option>
       <option value="27">Açores</option>
       <option value="28">Madeira</option>
      </select>
     </form>

     <br>

     <div class="botesdefiltrar">
      <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
      <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
     </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <h5 id="denuncia">Caso saiba de algum caso de violencia doméstica
     <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader" class="denunciastyle"
      target="_blank">denuncie aqui</a>
    </h5>

   </div>

   <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-6 meio">
   </div>

   <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 direita">
    <div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: agradeço a sua ajuda mas ja consegui resolver! a solução esta na pergunta em negrito

Comment: @DavidMv legal! Se vc ler minha resposta vai ver que é justamente o que vc colocou ai em negrito! ;)

Comment: tem razão! peço desculpa!

Comment: @DavidMv é que quando vc colocou 100VH vc limitou o tamanho da diva a 100VH, ela não cresceria mais que isso de forma alguma, ai não acompanhava o tamanho da div do lado que poderia ter mais de 100VH por exemplo. Abs

Answer (score 1):

Onde voce está a colocar as classes esquerda, meio e direita coloque também um id com o mesmo nome exemplo: `id="esquerda";`

E insira o seguinte script no fim do seu ficheiro:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var alturaEsquerda = $(#esquerda).height()
    $(#meio).height(alturaEsquerda);
    $(#direita).height(alturaEsquerda);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var alturaEsquerda = $(#esquerda).height()
    $(#meio).height(alturaEsquerda );
    $(#direita).height(alturaEsquerda);
    });
}).resize();
</script>
```

O script vai buscar a altura do elemento da esquerda e atribui a altura igual aos elementos do meio e direita.

Comment: agradeço a sua ajuda mas ja consegui resolver! a solução esta na pergunta em negrito